# multi-index pandas dataframe to a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, multi-index

I have a dataframe as following:

```
raw_data = {'regiment': ['Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts'],
    'company': ['1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd', '1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd','1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd'],
    'name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze', 'Jacon', 'Ryaner', 'Sone', 'Sloan', 'Piger', 'Riani', 'Ali'],
    'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 2, 3],
    'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 62, 70]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['regiment', 'company', 'name', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
```

if I groupby by two columns and count the size,

```
df.groupby(['regiment','company']).size()
```

I get the following:

```
regiment    company
Dragoons    1st        2
            2nd        2
Nighthawks  1st        2
            2nd        2
Scouts      1st        2
            2nd        2
dtype: int64
```

What I want as an output is a dictionary as following:

```
{'Dragoons':{'1st':2,'2nd':2},
 'Nighthawks': {'1st':2,'2nd':2}, 
  ... }
```

I tried different methods but to no avail. Is there relatively clean way to achieve the above?

Thank you so much in advance!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.groupby(['regiment','company']).size().unstack().to_dict(orient='index')
print (d)
{'Dragoons': {'2nd': 2, '1st': 2}, 
 'Nighthawks': {'2nd': 2, '1st': 2}, 
 'Scouts': {'2nd': 2, '1st': 2}}
```

Another solution, very similar as another answer:

```
from collections import Counter

df = {i: dict(Counter(x['company'])) for i, x in df.groupby('regiment')}
print (df)
{'Dragoons': {'2nd': 2, '1st': 2}, 
'Nighthawks': {'2nd': 2, '1st': 2}, 
'Scouts': {'2nd': 2, '1st': 2}}
```

But if use first solution, there hs to be problem with `NaN`s (it depends of data)

Sample:

```
raw_data = {'regiment': ['Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts'],
    'company': ['1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd', '1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd','1st', '1st', '2nd', '3rd'],
    'name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze', 'Jacon', 'Ryaner', 'Sone', 'Sloan', 'Piger', 'Riani', 'Ali'],
    'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 2, 3],
    'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 62, 70]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['regiment', 'company', 'name', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
print (df)
      regiment company      name  preTestScore  postTestScore
0   Nighthawks     1st    Miller             4             25
1   Nighthawks     1st  Jacobson            24             94
2   Nighthawks     2nd       Ali            31             57
3   Nighthawks     2nd    Milner             2             62
4     Dragoons     1st     Cooze             3             70
5     Dragoons     1st     Jacon             4             25
6     Dragoons     2nd    Ryaner            24             94
7     Dragoons     2nd      Sone            31             57
8       Scouts     1st     Sloan             2             62
9       Scouts     1st     Piger             3             70
10      Scouts     2nd     Riani             2             62
11      Scouts     3rd       Ali             3             70
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby(['regiment','company']).size().unstack()
print (df1)
company     1st  2nd  3rd
regiment                 
Dragoons    2.0  2.0  NaN
Nighthawks  2.0  2.0  NaN
Scouts      2.0  1.0  1.0

d = df1.to_dict(orient='index')
print (d)
{'Dragoons': {'3rd': nan, '2nd': 2.0, '1st': 2.0}, 
'Nighthawks': {'3rd': nan, '2nd': 2.0, '1st': 2.0}, 
'Scouts': {'3rd': 1.0, '2nd': 1.0, '1st': 2.0}}
```

Then is necessary use:

```
d = {i: dict(Counter(x['company'])) for i, x in df.groupby('regiment')}
print (d)
{'Dragoons': {'2nd': 2, '1st': 2}, 
'Nighthawks': {'2nd': 2, '1st': 2},
 'Scouts': {'3rd': 1, '2nd': 1, '1st': 2}}
```

Or another [John Galt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44823657/2901002) answer.

Comment: I find problem in my first answer - works only if all categories (like in your sample data). So more general is second answer or another solution...

Comment: I see. I ended up taking the 2nd solution since it does not produce keys with nans.

Answer (score 3):

You can reset the index after group by and pivot your data as per your need. Below code gives the required output.

```
df = df.groupby(['regiment','company']).size().reset_index()
print(pd.pivot_table(df, values=0, index='regiment', columns='company').to_dict(orient='index'))
```

output:

```
{'Nighthawks': {'2nd': 2, '1st': 2}, 'Scouts': {'2nd': 2, '1st': 2}, 'Dragoons': {'2nd': 2, '1st': 2}}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about creating dict with groups comprehension.

```
In [409]: {g:v['company'].value_counts().to_dict() for g, v in df.groupby('regiment')}
Out[409]:
{'Dragoons': {'1st': 2, '2nd': 2},
 'Nighthawks': {'1st': 2, '2nd': 2},
 'Scouts': {'1st': 2, '2nd': 2}}
```